# How to modify values selected by an IndexedTraversal?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Given a list of pairs `[(Double, Double)]`, I want to divide the second element of the pair by its index increased by one. Thought it is a job for an `IndexedTraversal`, but I just can't make it compile:

```
over (indexing (traverse . _2)) (\ix x -> x / fromIntegral (ix + 1)) [(2, 3)]
```

The above doesn't work because `over` expects a function of type `Double -> Double`. Is there an equivalent of `over` for `IndexedTraversal`?

Comment: Maybe
iover (indexing (traverse . _2)) (\ix x -> x / fromIntegral (ix + 1)) [(2, 3)]
?

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Comment: @xgrommx I suggest posting that as an answer.